# Object cannot be converted to int

Tags: android, listview

I am going to delete the specific data from list view after building the gradle there's an error says "error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int"

Code of DatabaseHelper

```
public void deletegroce(int groceId){
    String groceid[] = { String.valueOf(groceId) };
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    sqdb.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_GROCE_ID + " = ?", groceid);
    sqdb.close();
}
```

And here's my full code of Grocery_List and the error is located at line 65 which is  **"int dave = aList.get(position); dbhelper.deletegroce(dave);"**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grocery_list);
    lvGorc = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGroc);
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(Grocery_list.this);
    final List aList = dbhelper.getAllGroceries();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> La = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, aList);
    lvGorc.setAdapter(La);


    lvGorc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Grocery_list.this);
            adb.setTitle("Option");
            adb.setMessage("What do you want to do?");
            adb.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
            adb.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                }
            });
            adb.show();
        }
    });

    lvGorc.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Grocery_list.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the selected item?");
            adb.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    int dave = aList.get(position);
                    dbhelper.deletegroce(dave);

                    La.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            adb.show();
            return  true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which types of object contains in your list ?

Answer (score 1):

The `aList` you have defined is a `List` of objects. the `ArrayAdapter<String>` accepts all kind of objects lists and it will call `toString()` method, which all objects have it, to show it in the `ListView`.

When you try to get an object of `aList` it returns an object of that index which can not be cast to `int`.

I think you can simply take the `id` of your object and pass it into the `dbhelper.deletegroce(dave)`. if your `aList` is a `List` of `Integer` objects you can simply cast it to `int` by calling:

```
int dave = (int) aList.get(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 5th line in OnCreate method which says 
 final List aList = dbhelper.getAllGroceries();

it doesn't specify that aList is List of Integer. What does your getAllGroceries return?
You should also define your list as  final List aList = dbhelper.getAllGroceries();
and make sure dbhelper.getAllGroceries() return List of Integer data.